# Can't see live preview in Design Tab in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

So I'm getting started with Android Development and I have a little issue.

I can edit the Hello world text by accesing the XML file in the Text tab, but I cannot see anything "live" in the Design tab.

This is where I edit the text by editing the code

[image]

\added pictures for a better explanation\

so this is where I change the text from "Hello World!" to "Did you know?", but I cannot see the text, neither a button or anything else if I add them, in the Design tab, here:

This is where I don't see anything in the design tab, on the phone itself

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line in your `styles.xml` :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

into :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You need a succesfull build to have live preview. Build-->Make Project.
In your case as you see you have red mark for error in your code. Try to solve it, make a succesfull build and you ll have the preview.

Comment: I've built the project and it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

There's an error, try rebuilding it/show what error you are receiving. If you're starting out, rather use a `Relative Layout` instead of a `Constraint Layout`, at least till you're comfortable with the different layouts. `Constraint Layout` is relatively new and can be difficult to start with.

Here's some code to get started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="190dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps**:

1. Go to design tab
2. In the status bar you will see your phone model(like pixel, Nexus etc), API(24 ,26 etc).
3. In the right side of API button you will see one more option, select this and try all the options available there.

   I found holo the best by the way, rest your choice:)